# Как в style задать цвет выделенного элемента в Drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, background

Как в style задать цвет выделенного элемента в Drawer?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В дравабл создаешь селектор selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/press" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

И еще два файла
press.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#FF9D21"/>     
</shape>
```

и normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#8BC7EB"/>    
</shape>
```

Создаешь стиль для дровера и переопределяешь в нем нужные атрибуты

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NavMenu" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourcolor</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector</item>
  </style>
```

PS: код не проверял, но направление мысли понятно :)